# how can we show directly by the "definition" that free groups are not pseudofinite?

Tags: model-theory

$\textbf{Definition:}$
 An $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ is pseudofinite if for all $\mathcal{L}$-sentences $\sigma$, $\mathcal{M}\models σ$ implies
that there is a finite $\mathcal{M_{0}}$ such that $\mathcal{M_{0}} \models \sigma$.

Although, there exists a proof that says the centralizers of elements in a free group are definable and isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}, + )$, so free groups are not pseudofinite. (Assuming we know that $(\mathbb{Z}, + )$ is not pseudofinite group), how can we show directly by the "definition" that free groups are not pseudofinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to spell out the strategy outlined in the proof you refer to, first one observes that $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is not pseudofinite. One way to do this is to exhibit a definable function which is injective but not surjective, like the doubling function $f(x) = x + x$. So for example $$\left(\forall x\, \forall y\, (x + x = y+y \rightarrow x = y)\right)\land \left(\exists x\forall y\, (y+y \neq x)\right)$$
is true in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not in any finite group.

Now any non-trivial free group $(F,\cdot)$ interprets $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ as the centralizer of any non-identity element. So we just need to translate the above sentence through this interpretation.  For example, $$(\forall x\, \forall y\, (x\cdot x = y \cdot y \rightarrow x = y)) \land \exists z\, \exists x\, ((x\cdot z = z \cdot x) \land \forall y ((y\cdot z = z\cdot y)\rightarrow (y \cdot y \neq x)))$$
is true in $F$ but not in any finite group.

Explicitly, the sentence says that the squaring map $f(x) = x\cdot x$ is an injective function from the group to itself (and since if $x$ commutes with $z$, then $x\cdot x$ automatically commutes with $z$, this implies that $f$ restricts to an injective function $C(z)\to C(z)$ for any element $z$), and there is some element $z$ such that $f\colon C(z)\to C(z)$ is not surjective.

**Edit:** After reflecting on this, you may notice that the interpretation argument is a bit more complicated than necessary. In fact, the squaring map $f(x) = x\cdot x$ is already an injective but not surjective function $F\to F$, so we can use the sentence $$\left(\forall x\, \forall y\, (x \cdot x = y\cdot y \rightarrow x = y)\right)\land \left(\exists x\forall y\, (y\cdot y \neq x)\right)$$ just like in $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just may you please tell me more why $f$ in the second case, I mean in the free group is not surjective?  Also, in general, in the case where we are talking within a group and looking for a definable function, is not it necessary that the $f$ is a group homomorphism too?

Comment: @MaryamAjorlou If the centralizer $C(z)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$, and the doubling map $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ is not surjective, then the squaring map $C(z)\to C(z)$ is not surjective, right? More concretely, let $g$ be a generator of the free group. Then $g\in C(g)$, and $g$ is not the square of any element in $F$.

Comment: "Is not it necessary that the $f$ is a group homomorphism too?" Why would it be? The point is that when $X$ is a finite set, there is not function *of sets* $f\colon X\to X$ which is injective but not surjective. The group structure is irrelevant to this observation.